# How to find root subgroups

Tags: algebraic-groups, root-systems

$\newcommand{\GL}{\text{GL}}\newcommand{\diag}{\text{diag}}$For $G = \GL_n(k)$ let $B$ be the upper triangular matrices and $T$ be the diagonal matrices in $G$. In this case I understand that the positive roots $\Phi^+ = \{e_{ij}\}_{i< j}$ are given by
$$
e_{ij}(\diag(\lambda_1\dots \lambda_n)) = \lambda_i\lambda_j^{-1}.
$$
for $i<j$.

For each root $e_{ij}\in \Phi^+$ we get the *root subgroup* which I have been told is
$$
U_{e_{ij}} = \{I + \lambda E_{ij}\mid \lambda \in k\}.
$$
($E_{ij}$ is the matrix with zeros all over except a $1$ in the $ij$th entry.)

I would like to see how one actually computes these *root subgroups*. How was it determined that $U_{e_{ij}}$ looks like above? What is the definition of a root subgroup? How, using the definition, can one actually compute these root subgroups?

Answer (score 11):

Depending on your definitions, the "computation" of the root subgroups for $GL_n$ is mostly an unpacking of those definitions once the characters and positive roots have been determined.  Disclaimer: I will be using the definitions and conventions set out in Malle and Testerman's *Linear Algebraic Groups and Finite Groups of Lie Type*.

First, let me fix some notation (in addition to yours).  If $\alpha$ is a root of $G$, let $T_\alpha = (\ker \alpha)^\circ \leq T$ be the connected component of $\ker (\alpha: T \to k^\times)$, $C_\alpha = C_G(T_\alpha)$ be the centralizer of $T_\alpha$ in $G$, and $G_\alpha = [C_\alpha, C_\alpha]$ be the commutator subgroup of $C_\alpha$.  Let $B'$ be a Borel subgroup in $G_\alpha$.  (There is some ambiguity here, which is resolved in theory by considering the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ or $\mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}$ obtained -- see below.  But if we are dealing with the positive roots, then the correct choice of Borel subgroup here is $B' = B \cap G_\alpha$)  Then the root subgroup you are looking for is defined to be $U_\alpha = B'_u$, the subgroup of unipotent elements in $B'$.

In your specific case $G = GL_n(k)$, let $\alpha = e_{12}$.  (The computation for the other roots in similar, but more difficult to TeX.)  Also, assume $k \neq \mathbb{F}_2$.  We have
\begin{align*}
T_\alpha &= \{\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n): \lambda_1 = \lambda_2\} \\
C_\alpha &= \left\{\begin{pmatrix} * & * & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ * & * & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & * & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & * \end{pmatrix} \in GL_n(k) \right\} \\
G_\alpha &= \left\{\begin{pmatrix} * & * & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ * & * & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in SL_n(k) \right\}
\end{align*}

Notice that at this point we have basically reduced the problem to $SL_2(k)$. (This is common in other computations too.)  Continuing on with the computation,
\begin{align*}
B' &= \left\{\begin{pmatrix} * & * & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & * & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in SL_n(k) \right\} \\
U_\alpha &= \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & * & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}: * \in k \right\} 
\end{align*}

This is exactly the group $\{I + \lambda E_{12}\}$ you were looking for.

Some other remarks: the root subgroup can be defined in slightly different ways.  For example, $U_\alpha$ is the unique one-dimensional connected unipotent subgroup of $G$ normalized by $T$ with Lie algebra $\operatorname{Lie}(U_\alpha) = \mathfrak{g}_\alpha$, where $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ is the vector subspace corresponding to the root $\alpha$ in the root space decomposition of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.  From this perspective, $U_\alpha$ is also the unique one-parameter group in $G$ given by a morphism $u_\alpha: k \to G$ satisfying $tu_\alpha(c)t^{-1} = u_\alpha(\alpha(t)c)$ for all $t \in T$ and $c \in k$.  If you are willing to accept these facts, you can also just check that the root subgroups you are given have the required properties.